# Is it safe to access a local variable within the context of an anonymous thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-xe6

Given the below scenario, is the value of AValue in DoSomething as read by the anonymous thread guaranteed to be "readable"? ie, the value I'm expecting?  To me, I would think not as DoSomething goes out of scope (ie, returns) before the thread actually executes (which can be easily seen by realising that the line x := 2 always executes before my thread starts - although I guess with threads all bets are off and my thread *might* execute before DoSomething returns).

I only ask because I have never come across the scenario in my testing where AValue does not equal 1 (aka, the value passed in) so I'm wondering if some implicit reference is held to the procedure and/or thread (again unlikely as CreateAnonymousMethod simply creates an instance of a TThread descendant (TAnonymousThread) and calls my anonymous "execute" method).  I'm guessing though that it's the same because nothing (in this limited scenario) has overwritten the memory location of where AValue is stored.

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  x: Integer;
begin
  x := 1;
  DoSomething(x);
  x := 2;// this line is only here for the purposes of placing a break point
end;

procedure TForm2.DoSomething(AValue: Integer);
begin

  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    var
      y: Integer;
    begin
      y := AValue;

      if y = 1 then
        MessageBox(0, 'Same', 'Value', MB_ICONINFORMATION or MB_OK)
      else
        MessageBox(0, 'Different', 'Value', MB_ICONINFORMATION or MB_OK)
    end).Start;
end;
```

**EDIT**
Just to verify, I am wanting to know if it's safe to capture a local variable within the context of an anonymous thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing x by value. This means that the value of x is copied when you call `DoSomething()`.

So, whenever the anonymous thread is executed, it has no reference to x. 
The thread used a captured variable that is initialized with the original value of `x`.

In other words, the anonymous thread cannot see if you change x later in the `ButtonClick1` event.

---

Note, if you change the local `AValue` in `DoSomething()` after the anonymous thread is constructed, this will affect the outcome of your thread.

```
procedure TForm2.DoSomething(AValue: Integer);
begin

  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    var
      y: Integer;
    begin
      y := AValue;

      if y = 1 then
        MessageBox(0, 'Same', 'Value', MB_ICONINFORMATION or MB_OK)
      else
        MessageBox(0, 'Different', 'Value', MB_ICONINFORMATION or MB_OK)
    end).Start;
  AValue := 3;  // <-- This value will likely be seen by the anonymous thread.
end;
```

Should you want to avoid this scenario you can capture the `AValue` value like this:

```
procedure TForm4.DoSomething(AValue: Integer);
   function CaptureValue( y: Integer) : TProc;
   begin
     Result :=
      procedure
      begin
       if y = 1 then
         MessageBox(0, 'Same', 'Value', MB_ICONINFORMATION or MB_OK)
       else
         MessageBox(0, 'Different', 'Value', MB_ICONINFORMATION or MB_OK)
     end;
   end;
var
  p : TProc;
begin
  p := CaptureValue(AValue);
  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread( p)
  .Start;
  AValue := 3; // <-- The anonymous method is unaffected by this change !
end;
```

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Anonymous_Methods_in_Delphi#Variable_Binding_Mechanism) explains that the outer local variable AValue is captured by reference by the anonymous method:

> If an anonymous method refers to an outer local variable in its body, that variable is "captured". Capturing means extending the lifetime of the variable, so that it lives as long as the anonymous method value, rather than dying with its declaring routine. Note that variable capture captures variables--not values. If a variable's value changes after being captured by constructing an anonymous method, the value of the variable the anonymous method captured changes too, because they are the same variable with the same storage. Captured variables are stored on the heap, not the stack.

Comment: Yes, sorry.  I completely understand that x := 2 won't be reflected in the anonymous thread.  What I am wanting to know is if (in the above example - but also under more complicated scenarios) that AValue is guaranteed to be 1 when the thread is executed.  ie, it's "Thread Safe".

Comment: Updated answer. If you are changing AValue later in the DoSomething method, you are in trouble.

Comment: Yep.  Understand.  So I can safely assume that AValue will always be 1? ie my AnonymousThread can safely access local variables?

Comment: Except for the case I outlined, yes.

Comment: In the non-`CaptureValue()` example, yes.  `AValue` is initialized to 1 when `DoSomething()` is called, and the anonymous procedure captures `AValue` (not `x`), and nothing is changing `AValue`, so it is always 1 while the thread is running.  That is not the case in the `CaptureValue()` example.  `AValue` is changed to 3 while the thread is running, but it does not care as it did not capture `AValue` in the first place.